# Planck law near absolute zero

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, thermal-radiation, quantum-statistics

Is the [Planck law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) of radiation valid even for $T$ near absolute zero? Why can we be sure that the mean photon number inside a black body is zero for $T\to 0$?

Comment: Are you asking for experimental confirmation, or some kind of intuition about the theory?

Comment: At first I asked for some kind of intuition about the theory. But if there are convincing experimental confirmations that would also be good.

Answer (score 0):

There are no photons but harmonic oscillators inside a blackbody. At T=0, or rather at T=0.2K due to zero point energy, no photons are emitted since all of these harmonic oscillators are in the ground state. The number of photons emitted is zero.

Comment: If a harmonic oscillators from inside the black body emits a photon, how does it reach the exterior without to cross the interior of the body?

Comment: Photons are emitted from the surface, not from inside the black body. Remember we are discussing an ideal black body here.

Comment: As far as I understand, you say that the harmonic oscillators are at the surface of the blackbody too?